# How to Launch multiple Chrome Browsers in Parallel using TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, chromedriver, xml-file

I need to automate the two Web applications in parallel and that needs to validate in Chrome browsers.

So I have two testng XML files(**testng1.xml** and **testng2.xml**),  my scenario is to launch one chrome browser per xml file, so two chrome browsers in parallel.

Also I have common class for launching Chrome browser where I have initialized the webdriver.

**Launch Browser code:**

```
public class LaunchBrowser
{
    public static WebDriver driver = null;

    public LaunchBrowser()
    {

    }

    public LaunchBrowser(WebDriver drive)
    {
      driver=drive;
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

   @Test
   public void initDriver()
   {
     if (driver == null)
     {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
     }
 }
```

}

**testng1.xml**

```
<suite name="Suite1">

<test name="Browser">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ci.selenium.LaunchBrowser" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Google">
<classes>
        <class name="com.ci.selenium.Google" />
    </classes>
</test>


<test name="Gmail">
<classes>
        <class name="com.ci.selenium.GmailLogin" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

**testng2.xml**

```
 <suite name="Suite2">
   <test name="01StackOverflow">
     <classes>
       <class name="com.ci.selenium.Stackoverflow" />
     </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="02StackLogin">
     <classes>
        <class name="com.ci.selenium.StackLogin" />
     </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

**Google Class in xml1**

```
public class Google
{
   WebDriver d;

   LaunchBrowser l = new LaunchBrowser();

   @BeforeClass
   public void launch()
   {
     LaunchBrowser ll = new LaunchBrowser(d);
   }
   @Test
   public void f() throws InterruptedException
   {      
      l.getURL("https://www.google.co.in");
      Thread.sleep(3000);
      System.out.println("google");
   }
}
```

**GmailLogin Class in xml1**

```
 public class Gmail
 {
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException
    {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm'][text()='Gmail']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
  }
```

**StackOverflow class in xml2**

```
public class Stackoverflow
{
  WebDriver d1;

  LaunchBrowser l = new LaunchBrowser(d1);

  @Test
  public void f() throws InterruptedException 
  {
     System.out.println(l==null ? "null" : "not null");
     l.getURL("https://stackoverflow.com");
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     System.out.println("Stack");
  }
```

**StackOverflow Login**

```
 public class StackLogin
 {

    LaunchBrowser l = new LaunchBrowser();

    @Test
    public void f() throws InterruptedException
    {
      l.xpathClick("//a[@href='https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?
 ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f']")).click();
     Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
 }
```

The above code is not running in parallel exceution. So kindly help to resolve this scenario.

Comment: Did you do a google search on how to run a test cases in parallel in TestNG? Because there are already lot of material on it.

Comment: You have to configure the number of threads in testng.xml configuration.  One sample reference link: https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-executing-parallel-tests/

Comment: Hi Anok, I want to run the xml files in parallel, not the parallel execution of test methods. Since test method in each xml file depends on each other. For eg : If we want to login gmail account we need to go Google.com. So gmail login is depends on Google.com. Like that the two xml files were created.

Comment: My use case is, I have n number of XML test suite files and each xml file should run in individual chrome browser in parallel. Please let me the better solution to achieve this scenario.

Comment: You create two suite xml files and call that in testng.xml (Suite-of-suite). This should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810342/is-there-a-possible-way-to-run-two-xml-files-in-testng-xml-parallel

Comment: I have already tried this scenario, but it was not worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this scenario and works fine for me.

Please click the below link for the answer.

[One Browser per testNG XML Suite file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093802/parallel-execution-in-testng-using-maven/48540404#48540404)